# T SQL Cursor is only updating row with same value

Tags: sql-server, loops, t-sql, cursor

I'm using MS SQL Server and I have the below table 'tmp_AVG_Weekly_Sales':

```
RowID   SKU   Shop  Week   Avg_Value   LAMBDA    PMF      Value
  1     ABC   200    2       1          2        0.13     NULL
  2     DEF   250    2       2          4        0.018    NULL
  3     XYZ   300    3       3          6        0.0024   NULL
```

I need to work out the Value field based on the below logic - I am using a Cursor and Loop:

```
DECLARE @CUMULATIVE AS FLOAT = 0;
DECLARE @COUNT AS INT = 0;
DECLARE @LAMBDA AS FLOAT;
DECLARE @RowID AS INT;
DECLARE @PoissonCursor AS CURSOR;
DECLARE @THRESHOLD AS FLOAT = 0.99;
DECLARE @PMF AS FLOAT --= EXP(-@LAMBDA)


SET @PoissonCursor = CURSOR FOR

SELECT RowID
FROM 
[tmp_AVG_Weekly_Sales]

OPEN @PoissonCursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM @PoissonCursor INTO @RowID;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

    SELECT @LAMBDA = LAMBDA FROM [tmp_AVG_Weekly_Sales] WHERE RowID = @RowID

    SELECT @PMF = PMF FROM [tmp_AVG_Weekly_Sales] WHERE RowID = @RowID

    WHILE (@CUMULATIVE < @Threshold)

    BEGIN
        SET @CUMULATIVE += @PMF
        SET @COUNT += 1
        SET @PMF = @PMF * (@LAMBDA / @COUNT)

        END

        UPDATE [tmp_AVG_Weekly_Sales] SET [Value] = @COUNT - 1 WHERE RowID = @RowID

    FETCH NEXT FROM @PoissonCursor  INTO @RowID;

END
```

However, the above is just populating the Value field with the same value:

```
RowID   SKU   Shop  Week   Avg_Value   LAMBDA    PMF      Value
  1     ABC   200    2       1          2        0.13     6
  2     DEF   250    2       2          4        0.018    6
  3     XYZ   300    3       3          6        0.0024   6
```

When I am expecting the below:

```
RowID   SKU   Shop  Week   Avg_Value   LAMBDA    PMF      Value
  1     ABC   200    2       1          2        0.13     6
  2     DEF   250    2       2          4        0.018    9
  3     XYZ   300    3       3          6        0.0024   12
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that your calculation is correct? If I run the code, it goes on an endless loop because @PMF reaches 0 before reaching the Treshold. Also, the answer from gmiley shows why you're getting the same results for all rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never reset `@CUMULATIVE` or increase `@Threshold`, so the block of `SET` calls are only executed the first go through and each subsequent `UPDATE` just uses those original values.

Comment: @Threshold is set at 0.99

Comment: Yes, but `@CUMULATIVE` builds up to that (or more) on the first main iteration. You never reset `@CUMULATIVE` to 0, or increase `@THRESHOLD` to a higher number. So after the first iteration `@CUMULATIVE` is always greater than `@THREASHOLD` so the inner loop never executes.

Comment: @COUNT also needs to be reset.

Comment: @LuisCazares No, he wants a running total on `@COUNT`. (At least that was my understanding, if not, then yes that should be reset too.)

Comment: so I need to set @CUMULATIVE\COUNT to 0 after the update?

Comment: Yes for `@CUMULATIVE`, maybe for `@COUNT` depending on your desired output. I didn't bother re-calculating your equations.

Comment: Thanks, I have it working now.  Just need to improve the performance now!